# Word order: Can a sentence start with its object?

Tags: syntactic-analysis

Can the following sentence be considered as grammatically correct? :

"That(,) he doesn't need any more."

Comment: Yes, it's fine. The direct object "that" has been **preposed** to the front of the clause, probably to link it to the preceding discourse.

Comment: Thanks a lot, BillJ - it's hard to find information on exceptions like this one.

Comment: This is an example of the construction (transformation, rule, alternation) known as ***Left-Dislocation***. It appears at the bottom of page 4 on this mostly complete (at least very long) [list of known English transformational rules](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/haj/Preliminarybufattenedlistoftransformations.pdf) from Haj Ross.

Comment: To be left with an unanswered question, Jutta did not deserve.

Comment: It is not left dislocation -- it's preposing, a different construction. An example of left dislocation would be "**Her parents**, I don't like **them** at all", where the extra NP ("her parents") located to the left of the main part of the clause serves as antecedent for the personal pronoun ("them") within the nucleus.

Comment: @JohnLawler Isn't this Object preposing rather than left-dislocation? Wouldn't left-dislocation be something like "That book, he doesn't read **it** any more"? (Nice helpful link there)

Comment: Yes, you're both right. It's a movement rule rather than a copying rule. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 2):

***That***(,) he doesn't need any more.

Yes, it's fine. A complement of the verb - in this case the direct object "that" - has been preposed to the front of the clause, probably to link it to the preceding discourse.

Here are a few other pairs contrasting the basic order and the preposed one. The emboldened elements (two NPs and an adjective) are the complements that have been preposed in the second of each pair:

*I said he could have **the others***.  ~  ***The others*** I said he could have.

*They made **costume jewellery***  ~  ***Costume jewellery***, they made.

*Mr Brown is not **humble***. ~  ***Humble***, Mr Brown is not.

Comment: I immediately thought of Yoda . . . ;)